# Condition refactoring

Tags: if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I have a condition like:

```
A AND B OR NOT(A) AND NOT(B)
```

With some refactoring, I got this:

```
A AND B OR NOT(A OR B)
```

I'm searching the most refactored expression for this base.

If you have suggestions or tips, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: `A AND B AND NOT(A) AND NOT(B)` is always false

Comment: @Mike mistakes oops

Comment: In that case your refactored expression seems to be the most compact you can get unless you are using a language that offers XOR operator. And FYI there are plenty of online boolean expression simplifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Templar, @Mike and @Foxynh

The answer was just `A == B`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a negated XOR between A and B.

[XOR logical operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate)

Answer (score 1):

Are you programming that? Your case is a NOT XOR

Comment: I have this case in an if statement, just want to know if there is a solution to make it shorter